# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT. on laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I try to create a function to uptade a password.

in my controller:

```php
public function updatePassword($id) 
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    dd($user);
}
```

my button to open my page for update password

```xml
<div class="float-end">
    <form method="POST" action="myRoute.updatePassword">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
                    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Modifier le mot de passe
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and my route :

```php
Route::put('admin/update_password/{id}','MyController@updatePassword')->name('myRoute.updatePassword');
```

And when i click on the button, i have this error :

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.
```

Thanks for you'r help !

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you didn't put a URL in for the form action (`"myRoute.updatePassword"` isn't the URI for your route)  ... and that route you would like to use takes a parameter ... do you have some Javascript in play here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action:

```
<form method="POST" action="myRoute.updatePassword">
```

Should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('myRoute.updatePassword', $userId) }}">
```

You should pass the Id as a parameter since this is expected in your route and in your updatePassword method.

You can check more info about Laravel Routing in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Comment: Thanks you ! :) i forgot the id

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<form method="POST" action="myRoute.updatePassword">
```

Should be

```xml
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('myRoute.updatePassword') }}">
```

---

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#urls-for-named-routes